# What is /usr/bin/[ and how do I use it?

Tags: linux, bash, coreutils

I was looking at coreutils and found this as one of the files included as part of coreutils:  `/usr/bin/[`. What is `[` and what does it do?

It is an executable. I just don't know what it does or how to use it.

```
$ file /usr/bin/[  
/usr/bin/[: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared  libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

When I try to run it, I think it is defaulting to the bash built in line expansion. Instead of actually running the file.

```
$ "/usr/bin/["
/usr/bin/[: missing ‘]’
$ /usr/bin/\[
/usr/bin/[: missing ‘]’
```

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/138951/what-is-usr-bin

Comment: `man [` works on OS X.

Comment: Wow this is incredible. I panicked when I saw this on my system, almost deleted it, as it looks like a file you might have accidentally created (you know like you end up with files called `1` by using `>1` instead of `>&1` etc... maybe that's just me) I always thought `[` was (just) a builtin language thing. Now I'm looking out for `/bin/if` and `/bin/then` and `/bin/{`!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's an equivalent of the command `test`. (See `info test`.) Generally you use it in scripts in conditional expressions like:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo $1
fi
```

The closing bracket is required to enclose the conditional. (Well, it looks like its required just to look nicer in the code. Does anybody know any other practical reason for it?)

Comment: Note that `[` is *both* a shell built-in and a external program with the same (or similar) usage. In bash, when you run `[` or `test` you are invoking the built-in.

Comment: It's required because if it were optional the syntax would be ambiguous in certain situations.

Answer (score 23):

It is equivalent to the `test` command.

Instead of

```
if /usr/bin/test -z "$VAR"
then
    echo VAR not set
fi
```

You can use:

```
if /usr/bin/[ -z "$VAR" ]
then
    echo VAR not set
fi
```

It can be used in loops too:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
   echo $i
   ((i++))
done
```

You can also use them in one-liners like this:

```
[ -z "$VAR" ] && echo VAR not set && exit

[ -f foo.txt ] && cat foo.txt
```

Comment: nice examples of how to use it. "if /usr/bin/["